# PyCharm 'Cannot connect to already running IDE instance' error on Pop!_OS (Debian-based) - How to resolve?

Tags: python

While opening pycharm in pop os(debian based), it pops up this message:

```
Cannot connect to already running IDE instance.
Exception: Process 2 is still running
```

Please tell me how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to delete the IDE and reinstall it, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: kill -9 process_ID